# Get file name of file from full path?

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, filenames

I have DragDrop enabled in my WinForms application, I'm getting the list of items dropped and storing them in a string array called files, then in the DragDrop event I can do something like:

```
foreach (string file in files)
{
    MessageBox.Show(file);
}
```

Which would return something like:

```
C:\Users\MyName\document.txt
```

Is it possible to get just the file name + extension (e.g. document.txt)? I'm not asking for a complete solution, but could you hint me in that direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Path static function calls such as:

```
Path.GetFileName(someFullPath);
```

See [msdn here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx).

Comment: Thank you so much!! I had no idea that method existed.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class ..

```
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileFullPath);
        var name = fileInfo.Name;
        var extension = fileInfo.Extension;
```